# Turbolinks causes a link with href="#" to trigger page refresh

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ujs, turbolinks

I have a very simple link on my page. `<a href="#">My link</a>`. It causes a page refresh. when I remove "turbolinks", it no longer causes a refresh.

I've used links with hash fragments all the time in the past. Unless I've missed something very fundamental for a long time, I don't understand how this can cause a refresh.

It does not have any JS event handlers attached to it.

Any ideas?

It may not matter, but I'm using jQuery, Twitter-Bootstrap, and Ruby on Rails.

Clues so far:

- When I remove Turbolinks, the link behaves properly (does not cause page refresh).
- Links with "#" as the URL cause a reload on every page of my app.
- Links with any "#hasfragmenttext" will cause a single refresh and then the URL of the page is "mypage#hasfragmenttext", any additional clicks do NOT cause page refresh... hmm.

Comment: Can you post content of *head* tag of generated page?

Comment: had the same issue, this should not be the default behaviour, had to use https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks#disabling-turbolinks-on-specific-links

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `data-no-turbolink` attribute on that link the error should be gone

```
<a href="#" data-no-turbolink>My link</a>
```

Answer (score 23):

The above solution didn't work for me but this did :

```
<a href="#" data-turbolinks="false">My link</a>
```

This can be found at https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks

**update**: This solution works for turbolinks 5, for classic turbolinks check the previous answer by @wael34218

Comment: It also work for me, It looks better and it is included in official docs. It should be mark as answer

Comment: Just to clarify this original solution was for classic turbolinks.  This is for turbolinks 5

Answer (score 2):

With Rails 7 / Hotwire, you now need to use:

```
data-turbo="false"
```