# See all JS, events, network events but stop page from reloading

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I'm still working on this question [Turbolinks causes a link with href="#" to trigger page refresh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20510358/a-link-with-href-causes-page-refresh).

I have `<a href="#">Shouldn't refresh</a>` causing page refreshes. How can I see all events, js, etc. but prevent the page from reloading so I can debug this better?

**A new clue that I stumbled on!**

When I have `<a href="#test">Refreshes once</a>` I get this behavior:

1. Page URL is "mysite.com/hello"
2. click link (causes refresh)
3. Page URL is "mysite.com/hello#test"
4. click link (No refresh!!)

Also, I have no JS loaded in "sources" except for the jQuery library. I have no inline `<script>` tags either.

Answer:
Wow it turned out to be due to a Ruby-on-rails buit in feature called Turbolinks. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: Don't use `<a>` for this. There's an HTML element that is meant to be clickable but not be a link - it's called `<button>`.

Comment: If your page is really simple, do a jsfiddle

Comment: Can't repro in jsfiddle (seriously all thats on one of my pages is `<a href="#">Test</a>` and I still get the refresh. @Cuberto I agree, but it's still important to understand why an unexpected behavior is happening in my app.

Comment: If you are voting to close, please let me know why - it's usually something obvious that you may know :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a tab called "event listeners" in the "Elements" view of the dev tools. When you select a DOM Element, there will show you what events are attached to it. You can also filter by "all events" or "selected nodes only". Note that this will not show delegated events from it's parents.

Additionally, you have "DOM Breakpoints". You could add a breakpoint to an Element and it would behave just like a JavaScript breakpoint.

I assume you are familiar with the dev tools but there is also the "Sources" view where you find all JS and that allows you to add breakpoints to your code execution as well. There you will also find "Event Listener Breakpoints" that can be triggered on every defined event that may occur.

Comment: Thanks @DrColossos - how do I add a DOM breakpoint?

Comment: In the "Elements" view, right click on the element and select "break on" and whatever is appropriate.